# Document list inside div problem

Tags: list, document

I have document list web part on my page. That list is placed inside a div. When the list is placed inside the div, the drag and drop features stops working. They are working just fine when the list is outside of the div. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

The CSS for the parent div:

```
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
position: relative;
```

Comment: You're gonna have to post the code CSS.

Comment: @Colbs The CSS is added..

Comment: The webpart drag and drop is not very good. I have to use IE rather than Chrome or FF. Would it be acceptable to use jQuery to add the class only when Not in Edit mode?

Comment: What class are you talking about? I do want the user to be able to use the drag and drop without going into edit mode..

Comment: I'm sorry. You're talking about the drag and drop file feature of a library correct?

Comment: Yes. I have put a documents wep part on my site and that has a drag and drop feature